# My External CSS is not affecting into my index.html

Tags: html, css

I have made an external style sheet by CSS and it supposes it has effected my HTML files, but when I ran them on the atom. However, It does not seem to affect it into my index.html. I guess my input suppose correct, but I do not understand what is the reason it is not working. I am making my website practice at the moment and I hope there has someone who could give me the right support.

File name by CSS: css/styles.css

```css
body{
  background-color:#dbf6e9;
}

hr{
  border-style: none;
  border-top-style: dotted;
  border-color: grey;
  border-width: 5px;
  width:30%;
}


File name: index.html
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Peter Stinson's Personal Site</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</html>
```

Comment: Press F12 then look in the network tab and reload the page to see if the css is even found

Comment: You may need a hard refresh, usually `Ctrl + F5`.

Comment: Yes I saw that is in the element when I hit F12

Comment: costaparas - I did pressed Ctrl+F5 but still the same.

Comment: @anpanman can you give us the structure of your working tree?

Comment: You haven't opened the <head> but declared it..

Comment: I added <head> in the index.html already

Comment: Ganesh Kalyan Kommisetti Hold one let me add it

Comment: Ganesh Kalyan Kommisetti  I added but it still could not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution now.

What I did was exactly right.

I have created a folder called web-development, and I also created 2 sub-folders and one of that called Personal-site and the other one is called css.

It was not my fault I created styles.css to my sub-folder called css.  However, when I added  into my files: index.html under the sub-folder od Personal-site and there have no response when I click and check my font end.

After my investigation and I finally found out the issue.

1. I right-click in my page then I clicked for inspect.
2. I selected for the console- then I could see where is the bug.
3. I closed the inspect and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.
4. I clicked to the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">`
5. I realised there has no response with showing an error.  My subfolder- Personal-Site is not detecting any file from `css/styles.css`.
6. Because of that, I moved my whole subfolder- css to inside of my 1st subfolder-personal-site.
7. Then I clicked to my `index.html` page and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.
8. It work!!!

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML file is incorrect, it should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Peter Stinson's Personal Site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  </head>
</html> <!-- you put 'head' here... -->
```

If that wasn't the issue, make sure your project structure is:

```
Project (folder)
|-- index.html (HTML file)
|-- css (folder)
    |-- styles.css (CSS file)
```

If your project isn't very big, I would suggest your combine your files like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Peter Stinson's Personal Site</title>
    <style>
        body {
          background-color:#dbf6e9;
        }
        
        hr {
          border-style: none;
          border-top-style: dotted;
          border-color: grey;
          border-width: 5px;
          width:30%;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you mean i need to add <head> near the </html> ?  I could try but I feel curious.....

Comment: user11350388  I know i could combine all files but I am practising to create the external css.

Comment: No, I think you might have forgotten the '/html' tag, and instead put a 'head' tag(see the code in your question post).

Comment: Did you name your css file 'css/styles.css' or did you name it 'styles.css' and put it in a folder named 'css'? That's the only issue I can think of that would make the css file not style your webpage file...

Comment: Yes I do- </body>
</html>

Comment: user11350388 the folder is called css and the file name is called styles.css

Comment: Could you perhaps post your project tree structure?

Answer (score 0):

bro check your html file first and check where the "" tag is starting and ending also check "" tag and keep in mind that you have to link css file to the layout(main file of your page which will then extends) of your website and then extend it. In my case I am using pug view engine so mine looks like this: (on the left is the main layout and on the right is the index extending main layout)
[image]